# Query saved in table to run in different query's where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that have a list of "Reports" or "Correspondence Letters" (html files). This list will appear in a dropdown in a website. Some of these items will need a "check" to see if they are allowed to be added to the dropdown.

An example of how this table (I removed columns that was not necessary to display):
[image: MainTable]

In this table there is a column "Cor_PolNeedCheck_ToShow". This value links to a different table where the query for that file is stored.
[image]

From here I need to create a query that will build the actual list that will be displayed. But in order to do that I need to run the query that is in the second table to perform the check. I've created the following query to do this and it brings back the expected results:

```
    DECLARE @retvalue  INT
    DECLARE @Paramater NVARCHAR(20) = '241215'
    DECLARE @Cor_GroupCde NVARCHAR(10) = 248

    DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(500);

    SELECT @Statement = (SELECT Lookup_Query + @Paramater FROM [dbo].[Ref_Lookup] 
                WHERE Lookup_ID = (Select Cor_PolNeedCheck_ToShow  FROM dbo.Ref_Correspondence WHERE Cor_Group_Cde = @Cor_GroupCde));

    EXEC @retvalue = sp_executesql @Statement;
    PRINT @retvalue
```

This value needs to be passed into a query again to verify each record to show or not to show. This is the query that will run to show the items (I have added the @retvalue of the above in the query just to show what it needs to do). This query is in a stored proc where the @Paramater  will be passed (above) from the application and then to be used as needed for the below (as above query needs to fit into this one).

```
    SELECT Cor_Group_Cde, Cor_Desc
    FROM Ref_Correspondence
    WHERE Cor_Show = 'Y' AND Cor_Prod_List  Like '%#' + @ProdID + '#%'
    AND (Cor_PolNeedCheck_ToShow IS NULL OR --@retValue > 0)
```

The problem I'm facing is that I need to get the @retValue into the where clause. 
I have though of a stored proc, but a stored proc cannot be called in a where clause. I then though of a user defined function, but the problem there is that you cannot call a stored proc ("sp_executesql") in a function.

Due to company standards I cannot do this within the application either. Is there a way around this or is there a way to do this that I maybe missed with the above?

-------------------- EDIT ---------------------

The function I created looks like this:

```
    USE [DBName]
    GO
    /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ufn_CorrespondenceCheckResult]    Script Date: 4/11/2019 5:35:04 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_CorrespondenceCheckResult] 
    (
      @Paramater nvarchar(20),
      @Cor_GroupCde nvarchar(10)
    )
   RETURNS int
   AS
   BEGIN

DECLARE @Statement nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @Return int;

set @Return = 0;

SELECT @Statement = (SELECT Lookup_Query + @Paramater FROM [dbo].[Ref_Lookup] 
                WHERE Lookup_ID = (Select Cor_PolNeedCheck_ToShow  FROM dbo.Ref_Correspondence WHERE Cor_Group_Cde = @Cor_GroupCde));

EXEC @Return = sp_executesql @Statement;

return @Return;
```

END

Running the above function in my script gives me an error of "***Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.***":

```
    SELECT Cor_Group_Cde, Cor_Desc
FROM Ref_Correspondence
WHERE Cor_Show = 'Y' AND Cor_Prod_List  Like '%#' + @ProdID + '#%'
AND (Cor_PolNeedCheck_ToShow IS NULL OR ((SELECT [dbo].[ufn_CorrespondenceCheckResult] (@Paramater,@Cor_GroupCde)) > 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to convert your Stored Procedure into a Function, if possible. Then you can use function in WHERE clause.

If you can't convert it into the function then better to execute the SP and store the full result in a Variable. Now you can use This table in WHERE clause.

Comment: Thank you for the reccomendation, I have edited the above with the code for the function (getting an error of "Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function."

Answer (score 0):

You should store the result of the Stored Procedure in a variable in then use that in your next statement's condition. You can use an OUTPUT parameter to return the value of from the Stored Procedure.

```
DECLARE @count INT

EXEC FindProductByModel  --CREATE a stored procedure FindProductByModel  instead of a function
@Paramater = '241215',
@Cor_GroupCde = '248',
@retvalue= @count OUTPUT  --@retval is an output paramater of your stored procedure

SELECT Cor_Group_Cde, Cor_Desc
FROM Ref_Correspondence
WHERE Cor_Show = 'Y' AND Cor_Prod_List  Like '%#' + @ProdID + '#%'
AND (Cor_PolNeedCheck_ToShow IS NULL OR @count>0)
```